# How can i make to format date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have an a dataframe:

```
date                        USD 
2003-01-31T18:24:11+0300    40
```

I needed to make format like year-month like 2003-01

Tryed to do:

```
final_df['date'] =  pd.to_datetime(final_df['date'], format='%Y-%m')
```

and take exception:

```
'Styler' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is the error your got but you need to use [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html).

Try this :

```
final_df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(final_df['date']).dt.strftime("%Y-%m")
```

##### # Output:

```
print(final_df)
                       date  USD     Date
0  2003-01-31T18:24:11+0300   40  2003-01
```

Comment: also takes: Styler' object is not subscriptable

Comment: If you're using a styler datframe, make sure to put this line before any styling statement.